# How do I prevent strptime from throwing an error if my date isn't present or in the right format?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, date-format, strptime

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  In my controller, I have this when I’m about to save an entity

```
    @date = Date.strptime(my_object_params[:day], "%m/%d/%Y")
    @my_object.day = @date
        respond_to do |format|
      if @my_object.save
```

Unfortunately, if the parameter is not included or if it doesn’t match the format, I get this error

```
ArgumentError (invalid date):
  app/controllers/my_objects_controller.rb:33:in `strptime'
  app/controllers/my_objects_controller.rb:33:in `create'
```

How can I prevent Rails from dying if it doesn’t get the right format?  I have included this validation rule in my model, although I don’t think its getting to that stage yet, since my “Save” is not called until later in the method …

```
  validates_presence_of :day
```

Comment: Your stacktrace of the error has some line numbers, which lines in your code are these? And is that the whole stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try being more specific in your error handling?

```
begin
  @date = Date.strptime(my_object_params[:day], "%m/%d/%Y")
rescue ArgumentError => ae
  #do something rational and valid
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you simply add some error handling to the situation. Something like:

```
@date = Date.strptime(my_object_params[:day], "%m/%d/%Y") rescue nil
```

And then handle the situation where the @date is nil.

Comment: This doesn't work.  I replaced my line with yours but it still results in the same error I have listed in my question ("ArgumentError (invalid date)")

Comment: Then your error isn't caused by that line. If it where, the @date instance would be nil.